# Import JS / CSS from other application for HTML response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using an API which would return the response in HTML format to display the map.

Response also includes references to JS / CSS (Relative Paths on the server).

`E.g. <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/file.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/file1.css">`

Only two options I can think :

1- Create replica of folder/file structure on my application so relative URLS can be resolved.

2- Refer CSS / JS from other domain. (May require changes in header etc.)

Is there a better way to resolve CSS/JS  dependencies  ?

Comment: Do I get it right? You have a server A with an application running which uses some set of css and js files. And you have a server (site) B at which you want to refer to those files at server A to reuse them?

Comment: Yes exactly. HTML response from server A when displayed on server B wont work unless I have CSS / JS from server A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be two appropriate ways to handle this case:

1. Create a new route (or a set of routes) like `/css/.*` and use it as a "proxy" to the other site's content (user hits this route, your server downloads the file from the remote site and sends it to the response with an appropriate header). Ease of this way strongly depends on your architecture and programming skills.
2. Use a simplest regular expression you can come up with to replace `href` values to absolute ones including another site's domain. This one is easier to implement.